Extract uncaptured raw text from regex
I am given a regex expression that consists of raw text and capture groups. How can I extract all raw text snippets from it?
For example:
pattern = r"Date: (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})"
assert extract(pattern) == ["Date: ", "-", "-", ""]

Here, the last entry in the result is an empty string, indicating that there is no raw text after the last capture group.
The solution should not extract raw text within capture groups:
pattern = r"hello (world)"
assert extract(pattern) == ["hello ", ""]

The solution should work correctly with escaped characters too, for example:
pattern = r"\(born in (.*)\)"
assert extract(pattern) == ["(born in ", ")"]

Ideally, the solution should be efficient, avoiding looping over the string in Python.

Turn the capture groups into non-capture groups, and add capture groups around the other text.

I don't think there's any preexisting solution for this, you'll have to code it yourself.

It's a pretty unusual thing to do. Why is the regexp capturing the wrong parts to begin with?

What you are asking for is to extract literal tokens from a parsed regex pattern at the top level.
If you don't mind tapping into the internals of the re package, you can see from the list of tokens of a given pattern parsed by re._parser.parse:
import re

pattern = r"\(born in (.*)\)"
print(*re._parser.parse(pattern).data, sep='\n')

which outputs:
(LITERAL, 40)
(LITERAL, 98)
(LITERAL, 111)
(LITERAL, 114)
(LITERAL, 110)
(LITERAL, 32)
(LITERAL, 105)
(LITERAL, 110)
(LITERAL, 32)
(SUBPATTERN, (1, 0, 0, [(MAX_REPEAT, (0, MAXREPEAT, [(ANY, None)]))]))
(LITERAL, 41)

that all you need is to group together the LITERAL tokens and join their codepoints for output:
def extract(pattern):
    literal_groups = [[]]
    for op, value in re._parser.parse(pattern).data:
        if op is re._constants.LITERAL:
            literal_groups[-1].append(chr(value))
        else:
            literal_groups.append([])
    return list(map(''.join, literal_groups))

so that:
for pattern in (
    r"Date: (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})",
    r"hello (world)",
    r"\(born in (.*)\)"
):
    print(extract(pattern))

outputs:
['Date: ', '-', '-', '']
['hello ', '']
['(born in ', ')']

Demo here

very good answer!

There's no built-in method for this, but the span method of match objects can be used to create a sequence of slices to extract the non-group parts of the input string.
If the patterns will never contain nested groups, the solution is fairly simple:
import re

pattern = r"Date: (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})"
text = 'Date: 2024-11-14'
match = re.search(pattern, text)
    
spans = [match.start(),
         *(k for i in range(1, (match.lastindex or 0) + 1)
             for k in match.span(i) if k >= 0),
         match.end()]

raw = [text[spans[i]:spans[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(spans), 2)]

print(raw) # ['Date: ', '-', '-', '']

Handling nested groups (so that only the outer groups count), is slightly more verbose:
pattern = r"Date: ((\d{4})(-(\d{2})))-(\d{2})"
text = 'Date: 2024-11-14'
match = re.search(pattern, text)

spans = []
for i in range(1, (match.lastindex or 0) + 1):
    span = match.span(i)
    if span[0] >= 0 and (not spans or span[0] >= spans[-1]):
        spans.extend(span)
spans = [match.start(), *spans, match.end()]

raw = [text[spans[i]:spans[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(spans), 2)]

print(raw) # ['Date: ', '-', '']

Note that these solutions assume you're only interested in the section of the input string that is matched by the pattern. If you want to include the whole string, use 0 and len(text) as the first and last element of the spans instead.
